# How to create an Intellij Plugin which can simulate the Ctrl + F (find) functionality.

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

For Example : 
If I want to search for string : "ABC" in the currently opened file.
Instead of using CTRL + F and searching for "ABC".
I just want to click on the plugin so that it automatically searches for the string "ABC" in the currently opened file.

I wrote the code to detect currently opened file. But I am struct at implementing the CTRL + F functionality.

OR

Please tell me if there is any way to put a string for Example "ABC" inside ctrl+F field of Intellij and search automatically.

I am using java to write the code.

Comment: Is this a task you've been assigned? As the standard way isn't particularly cumbersome.

Comment: Why do you need an IntelliJ plugin to do this? Just [create a macro](https://autohotkey.com/) that presses CTRL + F, pauses briefly, then enters "ABC".

Comment: The person who uses this plugin doesn't know what he want to type in advance. So, I need to automatically fill the word in CTRL+F of Intellij or write a java program to implement CTRL+F on any file and give the search results for him. 
I have a array of strings to search for. So, If I know how to search for one string I can easily do it for the array of strings. So, it will be made easy for the person with one click on plugin instead of typing each string one by one.

Comment: What exactly do you need to accomplish? Do you need to navigate to the first occurrence of the string, or to highlight all occurrences, or to show all occurrences in a list? Ctrl-F is a complex workflow, and it's not clear which part of it you want to automate.

Comment: To put text into the Ctrl-F field, use EditorSearchSession.start() and then EditorSearchSession.setTextInField().

Comment: In the "search" window there is a dropdown that you can use to choose recently selected searches. It's really quite user friendly.

Comment: EditorSearchSession.setTextInField() is exactly the same thing which I am looking. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used it to

```
Project project = event.getProject();
```

Editor editor = event.getRequiredData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR);
EditorSearchSession.start(editor,project).setTextInField("Your Text to search");